# Can I make a series from a python class?

Tags: python, pandas, function, class, series

I am studying how to make an account book with python.

I want to make a series from items of 'Buy class': using values that I input at set_item() **in order to print 'name, price, change' at **wallet_info** process**, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

This is my incomplete code, please don't care about def print_r and elifs at the bottom yet:

```
import pandas as pd
args=sys.argv[1:]


class Buy:
    def __init__(self, name, money):
        self.name=name
        self.wallet=1000
        self.money=money

    def print_r(self):
        print(self.name, self.money, self.wallet)
        
    def wallet_info(self):
        self.name=name
        self.wallet-=self.money
        self.money=money
        print("you have", self.wallet, "now")   
        while True:
            answer=input("is it finished? (y/n) ")
            if answer=="y" or answer=="n":
                break
            else:
                print("wrong answer")
                continue
            if answer=="y":
                break
            else:
                continue
            
def set_item():
    name=input("what? ")
    money=int(input("how much? "))
    item=Buy(name,money)
    return item

def run():
    buyname=[]
    buymoney=[]
    for i in args:
        if i=="w":
            item=set_item()
            buyname.append(name)
            buymoney.append(money) 
            buylist=pd.Series(dtype='int', data=buymoney, index=buyname)
            buylist.loc[name]=money
            wallet_info(name)
        elif i=="r":
            list1(self)
        elif i=="x":
            x()
        else:
            print("wrong input")

if __name__=="__main__":
    run()
```

I would be very thankful if you help me.

Comment: *I want to make a series from items of 'Buy class'*. No you don't. If you want to store objects for `Buy` class, you'd better use a plain list. Pandas is based on numpy and is better at storing numeric values, date or time values, and strings. If you want to go the Pandas way, you should use a DataFrame where the columns are the attributes of the `Buy` class, to directly store *simple* types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this method to your class:

```
from copy import copy

@property
def pds(self):
    cls_dict = copy(self.__dict__)
    # # dropping all attributes which are not to be saved
    # self.drop = ['name']
    # for item in self.drop:
    #     if item in cls_dict.keys():
    #         del cls_dict[item]
    # creating a series from the resulting class-dict
    pds = pd.Series(cls_dict)
    return pds
```

This will return a pandas series with the attributes you have stored in your Buy-instance `buy` by calling `buy.pds`. If you want to modify the class dict I would suggest that you import `copy` and modify the copied one. Otherwise `copy` is not necessary.